# Quelle place pour l'innovation dans votre entreprise

Tags: traduction, questions

What is the meaning of:

> Quelle place pour l'innovation dans votre entreprise?

Quelle is What or Which, but in this context it seems it means something different like:

> Is there place for innovation in our company?

So, Quelle = is there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are quite right: *quel(s)/quelle(s)* is "what or which". But it cannot replace the verb and it does not mean "is there".

The sentence you quote:

> Quelle place pour l'innovation dans votre entreprise ?

is a question  with no verb.  If complete the question would read:

- Quelle est la place de l'innovation dans votre entreprise ?
- Quelle place tient l'innovation dans votre entreprise ?

The structure  *quel(le) + noun + pour* is used in questions and most usually found in headlines. Here are a few examples:

> Quel avenir pour la recherche européenne ? ([France culture](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/science-en-questions/quel-avenir-pour-la-recherche-europeenne))

> Quelle suite pour la lutte contre l'urgence climatique ? ([Heidi.news](https://www.heidi.news/sciences-climat/quelle-suite-pour-la-lutte-contre-le-changement-climatique))

> Plan France 2030 : quel rôle pour les collectivités ? ([La Tribune](https://www.latribune.fr/economie/france/plan-france-2030-quel-role-pour-les-collectivites-894240.html))

> Quel sort pour la dette Covid ? ([Challenges](https://www.challenges.fr/economie/quel-sort-pour-la-dette-covid_782875))

Comment: Thanks for your help.